# Swift 3 NSURL html Error does not compile

Tags: html, swift, ios9, swift3

I get the error "NSBundle has been changed to "Bundle", but even if changed, the problem is not solved. Guessing it is something else?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebVIew: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        WebVIew.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HtmlCOde"), ofType: "html")!)!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that you have an extra parentheses after the resource name. You should use Bundle.main.url(forResource:)

Comment: @LeoDabus WebVIew.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.urlForResource("HtmlCode", withExtension: "html")!)!))

Comment: @LeoDabus Error : Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: @LeoDabus Error: Value of type 'Bundle' has no member 'url'

Comment: @LeoDabus Xcode version 8 beta 3

Comment: @LeoDabus I will download beta 6 . current code: WebVIew.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: Bundle.main().url(forResource:"HtmlCode", withExtension: "html")))

Comment: @LeoDabus Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bundle' - tells me to delete "()" after main.

Comment: WebVIew.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HtmlCode", withExtension: "html")!))

Comment: @WeiJay Error: : Value of type 'Bundle' has no member 'url'

Comment: @yzet00 It works for me in Xcode 8 beta 6. make sure your URLRequest not NSURLRequest, Bundle.main.url not Bundle.main()

Comment: Use `URL`, not `NSURL`. Use `URLRequest`, not `NSURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `URL` instead of `NSURL`, `URLRequest` instead of `NSURLRequest`, and `Bundle` instead of `NSBundle`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "HtmlCode", ofType: "html")!)))
}
```

Or, better, excise the use of a `path`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HtmlCode", withExtension: "html")!))
}
```

I also changed the name of the `WebVIew` to `webView`, as properties/variables should generally start with a lowercase letter (but make sure to remove the old outlet and add a new one to the new property, if you do that).